# Pygame simplest possible shadow

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm looking for simplest way for 2d rectangles to cast "shadow" on objects that are "lower". I saw that there is a package for shadows, but that is a little bit too much for such a simple thing. Also I was wondering about gradients, but (in solutions I found) they are simply lines drawn side-by-side. Isn't there anything simpler?

My idea was to load images with border made of gradient 'black to transparent' already in the image, but I feel lazy about editing all the images every time I wish to change the "shadow".

Comment: You idea to load images is more adequate, and you dont need to edit them manually, write a program which creates the gradient in images. Generating shadows in runtime will be way too slow

Answer (score 2):

pygame.gfxdraw allows the drawing of transparent shapes.  Although this is an experimental library, you can use it to draw partially transparent black rectangles below all of your objects.  This is probably the simplest way to possible draw a shadow below an object.

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/gfxdraw.html

Comment: I will try that :)